Keyframes not working in blender, object is stuck at one place even after editing keyframes
Hello I'm new to blender. I am able to add keyframes and edit the location and rotation of my object but as soon as I hit play, it goes back to its original position. I was able to do it early but this started happening after I deleted all keyframes that I had created to create fresh keyframes.

Can you share a screenshot of your Blender File with the object selected ?

The correct order is  "select frame", "edit the location and rotation", then "add keyframe". Are you doing this?
